# Manually control <head> markup in Joomla

Tags: joomla, template-engine, joomla3.1

Is there a way to manually configure the contents of the `<head>` section of the site in Joomla 3.1? I want to use the templating system for the entire markup of the page, including everything between `<html></html>`.

I just read this: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=466&t=230787 and I am astonished at the response. Surely this is template/data separation 101. Has this been fixed in the latest Joomla release?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Chances are that these files have been re-written more than 2 times since the topic you posted (from 2007!) was created.

Comment: I want control over the HTML markup of all my pages, and specifically Joomla does not appear to provide this for the `head` section without core hacks. Meta tags, stylesheets, scripts etc.

Comment: Where is your code running? From a template or some other extension?

Comment: The rest of my page is built based on a template which I wrote - but `<jdoc:include type="head" />` spits out a bunch of stuff I don't want.

Comment: The reason why Joomla use `<jdoc:include type="head" />` is, it grabs all the content specified for the `<head>` and combines it into one. There are a lot of extensions that will need to include Javascript for example in the head using the `JHtml()` or `$doc->addScript()`. It simply makes life a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

If you are planning for a template development and you need all your template data get separated from Joomla libraries or core file (the head section).

Normally the head section include will works like

```
<jdoc:include type="head" />
```

it loads the content from libraries `libraries\joomla\document\html\renderer\head.php`

If you want to override the content of head you can make a module for your task.
Just create a module and include that module instead of this head make sure that have all required codes added to work `$document` Class otherwise it miss a lot off  features of Joomla regarding `document class`

Comment: Thanks - can you please explain your last sentence in more detail? Are there other side effects if I leave `<jdoc:include type="head" />` out entirely?

Comment: yes bcoz many components,modules,plugins etc are using document class for adding their style sheets scripts etc to the head section its rendering with this class

Answer (score 0):

As explained by the answer from Jobin, *normally*, you would include the head data by using the `<jdoc:include type="head" />` tag, but if you want more control over this, you can use the `JDocument`.

Example code in your template's PHP:

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$my_head_data = $doc->getHeadData();
```

This will give you an array of the data that JDocument would *normally* print, so that you can completely choose what to print and how.

Answer (score 0):

To make jQuery load from CDN and get it on top of the script list, I made a little patch just after the $doc = JFactory::getDocument(); that manipulates the header array directly inside the $this object as follows:

```
$my_jquery    = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js";
$my_jquery_ui = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js";
$my_jquery_cx = $this->baseurl."/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js ";

foreach($this->_scripts as $k=>$v) {
// put own jquery.conflict && jquery-ui && jquery on top of list
    if( strpos($k,'jquery.min.js')) {
        unset($this->_scripts[$k]);

        $r = array( $my_jquery_cx => $v);
        $this->_scripts = $r + $this->_scripts;

        $r = array( $my_jquery_ui => $v);
        $this->_scripts = $r + $this->_scripts;

        $r = array( $my_jquery => $v);
        $this->_scripts = $r + $this->_scripts;
    }
    else if( strpos($k,'jquery.ui.min.js')) {
        unset($this->_scripts[$k]);
    }
    else if( strpos($k,'jquery-noconflict.js')) {
        unset($this->_scripts[$k]);
    }
}
```

Replace $my_jquery_xxx with editable config parameters in your templateDetails.xml file