# joomla 3.x - how to include "metadescription" and "title" in the header without using <jdoc:include type="head" />

Tags: php, joomla

I am trying to get more control over the header of my Joomla site; for some pages I don't need many things in the header. I decided to make a template where I don't use the `<jdoc:include type="head" />`, because it loads lot of things that I don't need.

Searching, I found this old post about the subject, and in the web some people looking for the same thing. [Manually control <head> markup in Joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19720838/manually-control-head-markup-in-joomla)

I was wondering if it is possible to add to my `index.php` template file to PHP code that could get just the "metadescription" and the "title" of the Joomla publication. Something like this:

```html
  <?php defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die; ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>"> 
    <head> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width />
    <meta name="description" content="<?php echo **code metadescription** ?>" />
    <title><?php echo **code to get title** ?></title>
    </head>
    <body> 
    <jdoc:include type="component" />  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nice, after while i could find the code that i was looking for, and maybe it could help others, it worked for me... in the index.php file of the template i added:

```
<?php defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die;
$doc =JFactory::getDocument(); 
$meta_description = $doc->getMetaData("description"); 
$title = $doc->getTitle();
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" /> 
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo "$meta_description"; ?>" />
<title><?php echo "$title" ?></title> 
</head>
<body> <jdoc:include type="component" />  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just use PHP `include()` function**

In `top.php`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width />
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo **code meta description** ?>" />
<title><?php echo **code to get title** ?></title>
```

And in your current file just include the file(`top.php`) like

```
<?php defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die; ?>
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>"> 
    <head> 
    <?php include("top.php"); ?>
    </head>
    <body> 
    <jdoc:include type="component" />  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the tip, i am a php beginner , would be possible to help me with " **code for joomla core meta description** and  **code for joomla core title** " ... i could not find that yet :) , if i find i will post here 

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a good way, but you can unset all css and js in the following style:

```
unset($doc->_styleSheets[$this->baseurl.'/path/to/some.css']);
unset($doc->_scripts[$this->baseurl.'/path/to/some.js']);
```

I recommend not to remove meta tage like content-type or x-ua-compatible. These tags support your website in some browsers. And the favicon link is helpful by bookmarks.